# Install Ubuntu 15.04 with full disk encryption, but without swap partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap, lvm

I have a laptop with 16GB of RAM, but SSD is only 64GB. I need to install Ubuntu 15.04 with both standard options - "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security" and "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation". I don't want to create a swap partition, or at the very least I need to decrease it to the minimum, because by default it's taking up 16GB that will never be used.

How can I make this work? If I choose "Something else" I can't see any clear options how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ubuntu installer (*ubiquity*) is quite limited in this regard. So we need to do it manually instead of the installer.

So when you run the Live CD/USB, choose "Try ubuntu", and launch *gparted* to partition your drive.

You need to make an *ESP* (sda1) (if you use EFI+GPT), a *boot* partition (256MB for example, sda2), another partition (for example, sda3) that will hold the crypted container called *LUKS*.

Then open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t)

## Setup LUKS device

```
sudo cryptsetup --key-size 512 luksFormat /dev/sda3
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 crypted
```

## Setup LVM on LUKS

If you don't want to use multiple partition, you can skip the following paragraph and avoid LVM. In that case, use `/dev/mapper/crypted` as you root latter on instead

```
sudo pvcreate  /dev/mapper/crypted
sudo vgcreate vg /dev/mapper/crypted
sudo lvcreate -L 15G vg -n root
sudo lvcreate -l 100%FREE vg -n home
```

## Installation

Keep the terminal opened and now run the installation. Choose "Something else" when partitioning and specify

- your boot partition (/dev/sda2)
- your root partition (/dev/mapper/vg-root)
- your home partition (/dev/mapper/vg-home)
- any other needed partition...
- and check the checkbox to format your partitions

At the end of the installation, don't reboot but just click "Continue trying ubuntu"

## Post-install

In our opened terminal:

Create `/etc/crypttab` to add crypted partition

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg-root /mnt
echo "crypted UUID=`blkid -o value /dev/sda3|head -1` none luks" | sudo tee /mnt/etc/crypttab
sudo umount /mnt
```

That's it ! Reboot now.

Comment: We also need to chroot into the environment and `update-initramfs -u` else it won't boot:  http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer is too complicated, you can also just let the installer do its thing, then boot Ubuntu and install the LVM manager `kpvm`. With it, you can delete the `swap` partition and resize the root partition to use that space.

[image: kpvm screenshot with swap volume]