# Install Ubuntu with full disk encryption - /dev/mapper/vg-root does not exist

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, swap, initramfs

I want to install Ubuntu with full disk encryption without swap. Therefore I've followed: [Install Ubuntu 15.04 with full disk encryption, but without swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623814/install-ubuntu-15-04-with-full-disk-encryption-but-without-swap-partition)

It didn't work, thus I've also followed step 6, 7 (without fstab) and 8 from [Full disk encryption with Ubuntu](http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu). 
Everything went fine, without errors, despite the fact after reboot I see following error:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common Problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 - Check rootdelay = (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Check root = (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing module (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/vg-root does not exist. Dropping to shell!
```

Does anyone have idea why linux doesn't see vg-root?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gave up waiting for root device, ubuntu--vg-root doesnt exist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567730/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-ubuntu-vg-root-doesnt-exist)