# Bitlocker Windows 10 after ubuntu installation

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, encryption, windows-10

I installed Windows 10 on my main SSD then installed Ubuntu 16.04 after. I ran the Ubuntu setup and checked the option to install ubuntu with Windows 10.

Now I want to use BitLocker on Windows 10. If I encrypt my Windows 10 partition with BitLocker, will I still have access to Ubuntu and Windows 10?

Because I think GRUB (not sure) manages which OS boot at the start of my PC.

[image]

That's what prompts me before booting into a OS. It's just an example from Google, but I have Windows and Ubuntu in that menu.

Thanks,

Comment: **Apparently BitLocker is Windows/NTFS only**, so your Ubuntu partition should be safe, according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/960895/860611).